# Testing if an infinite sum of integrals converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need help testing if this series converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\sin(n)/n}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx $$

How should I approach a series with integral?

Comment: where is the $n$ in the integrand

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner fixed

Comment: Can you find a simple equivalent of the $n$th term? Is this equivalent sufficient to determine the convergence of the series? If not, can you add a second term to your equivalent? To sum up: **do something!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice exercise. First things first: for the sake of convergence, the contribute given by small $n$s is irrelevant, hence we may assume that $n$ is a large positive integer. The interval with endpoints $0$ and $\frac{\sin n}{n}$ has a length that does not exceed $\frac{1}{n}$, and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$. With more accuracy, the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is bounded between $1$ and $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$ on the interval $\left[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right]$, so your series is convergent iff
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{\frac{\sin n}{n}}1\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin n}{n} $$
is convergent. The last series is convergent (conditionally, but not absolutely) by Dirichlet's test, since $\{\sin n\}_{n\geq 1}$ has bounded partial sums and $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is decreasing to zero. Actually $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin n}{n}=\frac{\pi-1}{2}$ can be proved in a variety of ways, but that is not really relevant: since $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin n}{n}$ is (conditionally) convergent, your series is (conditionally) convergent too.

Comment: thank you, it's been long since I have seen such a deeply explained answer. you might just saved me with the test tomorrow :)